# How to make 4 digits 7 segments common cathode thermometer

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm new to Arduino and I have this problem: The common cathode 4 digits 7-segments keep on blinking even the code and my connection is correct (in my opition). I have used an LM35 IC to read the temperature
 I've just followed this pattern:[image]
and I used this code:

```
const int digitPins[4] = {5,4,3,2}; //4 common CATHODE pins of the display (inverted the pins order)
const int clockPin = 7;    //74HC595 Pin 11
const int latchPin = 8;    //74HC595 Pin 12
const int dataPin = 12;     //74HC595 Pin 14
const int tempPin = A0;     //temperature sensor pin
const byte digit[10] =      //seven segment digits in bits
{
  B00111111, //0
  B00000110, //1
  B01011011, //2
  B01001111, //3
  B01100110, //4
  B01101101, //5
  B01111101, //6
  B00000111, //7
  B01111111, //8
  B01101111  //9
};
int digitBuffer[4] = {0};
int digitScan = 0;
float tempC; //Deleted kelvin and farenheit

void setup(){               
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    pinMode(digitPins[i],OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);
  //Serial.begin(9600);
}

//writes the temperature on display
void updateDisp(){

  for(byte j=0; j<4; j++) {digitalWrite(digitPins[j], HIGH);} // Turns the display off. Changed to HIGH
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW); 
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, B00000000);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(digitPins[digitScan], LOW); //Changed to LOW for turning the leds on.

  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW); 
  if(digitScan==2)
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, (digit[digitBuffer[digitScan]] | B10000000)); //print the decimal point on the 3rd digit
  else
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, digit[digitBuffer[digitScan]]);

  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

  digitScan++;
  if(digitScan>3) digitScan=0;
}


void loop(){
  tempC = analogRead(tempPin)*0.00488;  //multiplied for this conversion constant
  tempC = tempC*10000;
  digitBuffer[3] = int(tempC)/1000;
  digitBuffer[2] = (int(tempC)%1000)/100;
  digitBuffer[1] = (int(tempC)%100)/10;
  digitBuffer[0] = (int(tempC)%100)%10;

  if (digitBuffer[0]>=5) {
    digitBuffer[0] = 5;
  }
  else {
    digitBuffer[0] = 0;
  }

  delay(5);
  updateDisp();
}
```

Comment: Who designed that circuit?

Comment: By "blinking" do you mean the display is showing the right thing but it's just flickering, or it's just flashing random stuff on and off?

Comment: it just flashing random stuff sir Majenko.

Comment: I just saw it on a comment in this link https://www.instructables.com/id/Temperature-Displayed-on-4-Digit-7-segment-common/

Comment: Ah right, well maybe using the original circuit from the instructable may be better - that one is using its resistors completely wrong, and if something so basic is wrong then I can't vouch for the rest of the circuit being right...

Comment: i cannot use the original circuit sir because i'm just using 12 pins 4 digits 7 segments while he is using 16 pins sir

Comment: Looks like he's using a 12 pin display to me - even the pin layout is the same. Follow the wires and note the order. Ignore the fact he is showing it with individual displays - that'll just be because he didn't have the real one in Fritzing.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you want to use the shift register? The Uno has enough pins o drive the display directly without need of a shift register, and you'll get a much smoother display (no delays while it shifts). You could even drive it with a timer interrupt to make it even smoother.

Comment: because sir later i will need the other pins to use fire sensor,light sensor,buzzer, tilt and LEDs

Comment: Maybe removing the 5ms delay from your loop may improve things a little.

Comment: A better way is to have the resistors on the anode side of the LED instead as this will help balance any uneven voltage drop of the diodes.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is that you have the IC and the 7-segment display module connected the correct way around. As a reference, the green wire is attached to Pin 14 of the 74HC595 IC, so pin 1 would be the top right pin. The 7-segment display should have the the dot points towards the bottom.

Check that you have a common cathode display. You can do this by applying a voltage, through a 220 ohm resistor, verifying that it lights up when positive is on pins A-G and Gnd connected to the common cathode pin.

Check the code by removing the temperature section of the code and just writing '0's to all 4 digits. In fact it would be worth testing the digits one by one. The below code should do just that (unverified):

```cpp
const int clockPin = 7;    //74HC595 Pin 11
const int latchPin = 8;    //74HC595 Pin 12
const int dataPin = 12;    //74HC595 Pin 14
const int digitPins[4] = {5,4,3,2};

void setup(){               
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    pinMode(digitPins[i],OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(digitPins[i], HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT); 
}


void loop() {
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    //select the digit by enabling the common cathode (sink)
    digitalWrite(digitPins[i], LOW);

    // write '0'
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 63);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

This code will display a '0' one digit at a time, each for 1 second.  If this code works then I suspect the problem lies in the `updateDisp()` function.

NB: In your code, tempPin is setup twice as an input.

Comment: In the line `shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 63);`, the number `63` may actually be `252` depending on which way the wires A-G are wired to the shift register. You could always use `255` to turn on all bits from the shift register.